# asp.net and signalR , JsonException: A possible object cycle was detected

Tags: asp.net, angular, signalr, signalr-hub, signalr.client

i am currently working on a project using asp.net 5 anuglar 12 and signalR.
while feching data from the server i am facing below error

"Utils.js:190 Error: Connection disconnected with error 'Error: Server returned an error on close: Connection closed with an error. JsonException: A possible object cycle was detected. This can either be due to a cycle or if the object depth is larger than the maximum allowed depth of 64. Consider using ReferenceHandler.Preserve on JsonSerializerOptions to support cycles.'."

my object which i am returning is below

```
    public class TeamBreaksDashboard
{
    public List<ChartConfiguration> TeamBreaksDashboardDetails { get; set; }
    public TeamBreaksDashboard()
    {
        TeamBreaksDashboardDetails = new List<ChartConfiguration>();
    }
}
public class ChartConfiguration
{
    public string ChartKey { get; set; }
    public string ChartName { get; set; }
    public List<DashboardData> DashboardData { get; set; }
    public ChartConfiguration()
    {
        DashboardData = new List<DashboardData>();
    }
}
public class DashboardData
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Value { get; set; }
    public string Color { get; set; }
}
```

the error is about the object cycle issue but i am not seeing any cycle in the code, i try using the below code in my startup.cs but not luck

```
            .AddNewtonsoftJson(options =>
        options.SerializerSettings.ReferenceLoopHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore
        );
```

Answer (score 2):

the issue was with the async method

```
        public async Task<TeamBreaksDashboard> GetTeamBreakss()
    {
        var teamBreaksDashboard = await _dashboardService.GetTeamBreaksDashboardDetails();

        if (teamBreaksDashboard == null)
        {
            throw new TGAppException($"no records fount.");
        }
        _ = new TimerManager(() =>_hub.Clients.All.SendAsync("transferdashboarddata", _dashboardService.GetTeamBreaksDashboardDetails()));

        return teamBreaksDashboard;
    }
```

i change the above code to the below

```
    public async Task<TeamBreaksDashboard> GetTeamBreaks()
    {
        var teamBreaksDashboard = await _dashboardService.GetTeamBreaksDashboardDetails();

        if (teamBreaksDashboard == null)
        {
            throw new TGAppException($"no records fount.");
        }
        _ = new TimerManager(async () => await _hub.Clients.All.SendAsync("transferdashboarddata", await _dashboardService.GetTeamBreaksDashboardDetails()));

        return teamBreaksDashboard;
    }
```